# JQuery Update text in a select dropdown list

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update the text of one of the options on a select dropdown after an action on my page. Does anyone know how to do this in jquery? I have tried this:

```
$("#selectid").text("newtext");
```

But that will remove all of the other options in the select list and it makes it blank. I know this is not the right approach because I just want to update one of the option values. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$('#selectid option:eq(NUMERIC_INDEX_GOES_HERE)').text('newtext');
```

or

```
$('#selectid').find('option[value="OPTION_VALUE"]').text('newtext');
```

or

```
$('#selectid option').filter('[value="OPTION_VALUE"]').text('newtext');
```

or

```
$('#selectid option:contains("OLD_TEXT_VALUE")').text('newtext');
```

Answer (score 0):

And to change the option's value, you can of course use:

```
$('#selectid option:eq(NUMERIC_INDEX_GOES_HERE)').val('new value goes here');
```